# Skip blanks while running "For loop"

Tags: excel, vba

Hello i write simple code to compare dates in range:
"starting from cell "G9" till end of column" 
compare dates in this range with today's date and return the difference in days to be placed the corresponding cell in column "P"

The problem is: i need to skip blanks while looping so if the cell is blank vba will skip and go to next cell

```
Sub overduedate()
    Dim LastRow  As Long, i As Long

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 9 To LastRow
            .Range("P" & i).Value = DateDiff("d", .Range("G" & i).Value, Date)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim cell as range` Then in the loop just add the condition `If cell.value <> vbNullString Then  'run code after this event`

Comment: Where should i put the "End If" ?

Comment: I did it by adding:

If Range("G" & i) <> "" Then
            
                .Range("P" & i).Value = DateDiff("d", .Range("G" & i).Value, Date)

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
Sub overduedate()
    Dim LastRow  As Long, i As Long
    Dim cell as range

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 9 To LastRow
            If cell.value <> vbNullString then
                .Range("P" & i).Value = DateDiff("d", .Range("G" & i).Value, Date)
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Or you can use the `If` Statement without the `End If` like below:

```
Sub overduedate()
    Dim LastRow  As Long, i As Long
    Dim cell as range

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 9 To LastRow
            If cell.Value <> vbNullString then .Range("P" & i).Value = DateDiff("d", .Range("G" & i).Value, Date)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: both ways are highlighting this line "If cell.Value <> vbNullString Then" and giving me "Object Required" error

Comment: you need to add `Dim cell As Range`